# Anti-concentration for Bernoulli summation

Tags: pr.probability, measure-concentration, bernoulli-numbers

Suppose $\{ Y_i\}_{i = 1}^n$ is i.i.d. Bernoulli distribution with mean $p$. Denote the sample of $\{ Y_i\}_{i = 1}^n$ as $\overline{Y} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i$. I want to know where there exists a constant $c_1 = c_1(p) > 0$ and $c_2 = c_2(p) > 0$ such that
$$
    \mathrm{P} \left(p - \overline{Y} > \frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}\right) \geq c_2 \exp \{ - c_1 t^2\}
$$
for any $t \in (0, 1)$ and any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: $p-\bar{Y}$ can't be bigger than $1$, which seems to give a problem for $t\geq \sqrt{n}$.

Comment: @JamesMartin Thanks for your comment. Edited.

Comment: This seems to follow from the CLT. Also, the exponential function is pointless since it is bounded below by a positive constant, so can be absorbed by $c_2$.

Comment: Indeed (assuming this is meant to be "for all sufficiently large $n$". For $n$ with $p< 1/\sqrt{n}$ you would again have the problem that the event in question may have probability $0$.)

Comment: Edited again. Thx!